# To what degree are font-families consistent across all browsers?

Tags: html, css

Is the following true:

1. I set the `font-family` on an element to sans-serif. My (Chrome) sans-serif font is Helvetica. There is a chance this web-page, when opened in another browser with a potentially different operating system, will render a different `font-family` as its sans-serif `font-family` may be different to mine e.g. cailbri
2. A font-family like Helvetica is a universal font-family that renders the same (dimensions) in all browsers.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) No, you should always specify a [generic family](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#%3Cgeneric-name%3E) *and* even if “Helvetica” gets a match it’s not guaranteed to be the same match everywhere. (Actually, it rarely will be.)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to ensure that the same font is used in all browsers is not by just setting the `font-family` to a generic value (like `sans-serif`), but rather using the `@import` or `<link rel="stylesheet" href="font.css" />` in your HTML code. In the `href` part of the link, and after the `@import`, you would place the URL to your font. For example, if I want to use the font "Ubuntu" (which is also a name of a Linux distro), and this font is served by Google Fonts, do this:

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap)
```

HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
```

You can then in your CSS (for the "Ubuntu" font) do this:

```
font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif; /* It is always smart to add the type of font at the end. In this case, sans-serif */
```

This ensures that all browsers that read HTML and CSS can use this font, and that it will not vary across common browsers.

Comment: Thanks @JasonD'Silva. I'm guessing this is the most popular technique amongst web developers?

Comment: @tonitone106 Me being a fellow learner in the world of web development, I am not 100% sure that ALL companies and developers use this technique, as many popular sites (microsoft.com, google.com, apple.com, etc.) don't like to link to other sites in their source code. But the best practice is to use one font for the whole site (including all pages), so that the user interface stays consistent. And, when doing this, it is better to download the styles for the font, rather than linking to another site (like fonts.google.com) to get them, just in case that their servers unexpectadely go down also.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is true. Actually, sans-serif is a large family of fonts. If the user (1) doesn't have the font you wanted in their computer, or (2) the user set their preferred font in their browser settings, the font will be different.

The second one *may* be true, but an extreme example is, the user deletes the Helvetica font from their computer. Some of the ways to avoid the problem is (1) set a fallback font, or (2) request a font on-line, like font.googleapis.com.

Comment: No, the second one isn't true.  Even users with the exact same font, same OS, same browser, may see different font rendering due to GPU differences, display settings, scaling settings, etc.